# Interpolating tags attribute values in a ngFor always gets "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected" error

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme

I'm using a [Devextreme's Datatable](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/Overview/Angular/Light/) and I wanted to dynamically configure the table via a columns configuration array.

The idea was to iterate this array with an `ngFor` and set column tags properties dynamically.

The question is: **how can we interpolate/inject/dinamically set the value of HTML attributes inside an `ngFor`?**

Here's what I tried so far…

1) Tried with a simple string interpolation:

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" caption="{{col.caption}}" [visible]="{{col.show}}"></dxi-column>
```

But I got the following error:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

2) Tried with `[attr.XXXX]={{}}` and string interpolation so I got:

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [attr.caption]="{{col.caption}}" [attr.visible]="{{col.show}}"></dxi-column>
```

But I got always the following error:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

3) Tried with a desperate, wrong and awful try…

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [attr.caption]=col.caption [attr.visible]=col.show></dxi-column>
```

But nothing, still not working (this try was not likely to work but was a quite desperate one).

Just for general knowledge, here's also my test configuration array, if interested:

```
  id: TableCol = {datafield:"id", show:"true" };
  desc: TableCol = {datafield:"idNodo", show:"showdesc"};

  columns: TableCol[] = [this.id, this.desc]
```

*PS: I will be available for any clarification, if needed*

Comment: Have you tried with something like this: `[caption]="col.caption"`? (I haven't tested and I can't test it right now so I could be wrong)

Comment: @Deadpool Tried and it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove it when you are using the input syntax, so remove from visible

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" caption="{{col.caption}}" [visible]="col.show"></dxi-column>
```

or

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" caption="{{col.caption}}" visible="{{col.show}}"></dxi-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like previous, or use brackets:

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [caption]="col.caption" [visible]="col.show"></dxi-column>
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: For devextreme front-end products, you can see examples on they official site -> Demos

Comment: For example, for dx-data-grid, you can set different settings, for elements like dxi-column like caption, visible, width and many other. If you write some of these options in the brackets (for example: [visible]), you can set value from component without {{}}. Like this: [visible] ="myVariable". Devextreme library interpolate your variable by itself.